# i have a problem with my site can't indexing

Tags: blogger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2adP1.png)[please help me what can I do to fix this error?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkU89.png)

please help me what can I do to fix this error

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably caused for many reasons like :
1/ switching from HTTP to HTTPS
2/ Existence Of Broken Links On Your Blogger Blog Pages I.E. Internal Links 
3/ Presence Of Invalid Links 
4/ Existence Of Incorrect Links 
5/ Old Or Wrong URLs 
6/ Deleted Or Updated URLs 
can be one or multiple reasons .